# What is the long-term career future for Dynamics CRM developers?

Tags: software-industry, careers

I have been working with Dynamics CRM in my company for six months and I really enjoy it. But I am at a possible crossroad to do something else, like frontend development, more intense .NET/C# and more.

I aim at going all in with Dynamics CRM (and the .NET/C# that comes with it).
From what I hear its "the future" and sounds very prosporous, but is it a viable long-term goal to become an expert in?

I ask in this forum to get an updated answer. I have googled similar questions which have positive answers, but they are a few years old, which ofc. is a lifetime in the software industry.

Comment: I literally LOLed at "from what I hear its 'the future'".  God, no one I know would touch Dynamics CRM with a barge pole, and I dropped it after version 4.  Use your .Net skills to make your skillset more diverse - ASP.Net, WPF etc etc. Thats your "future".

Comment: Allright, so what makes it so bad or undesirable? And do you thing that this is a shared or general opinion?

Comment: Thats probably more a topic for chat...

Comment: Diversify, diversify, diversify.

Comment: Do you care to elaborate on that Jimm101? Your comment is sarcastic un-diverse ;)

Comment: ToFo - being limited to one specialisation means your future is determined by the success or otherwise of that specialisation. Diversification protects you.

Comment: Well I agree, its the age old balance between being a generalist or a specialist i suppose

Comment: Rory might be correct in his comment here, but there remains the fact that SQL/SharePoint/C# aren't technologies that are going to fail at any point soon.  Enterprise level applications are likely to stick with the most robust technologies.

Comment: Which spawns the question "Is Dynamics CRM a robust  technology?"

Comment: @ToFo even robust technology's break down, most of it depends on wether something cheaper and easyer is being published and if Company are willing to invest into useing that System.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's still viable.  You're working with C#, CRM, business logic, SharePoint, SQL (I assume).  All of these skills are transferrable to later technologies if you decide to move on.

If you're enjoying where you are, stay and grow until you're no longer enjoying it.  There's a lot of cool new things out there, but you have the core skills right there. SQL/SharePoint/C# aren't going away any time soon.

I learnt COBOL back in the 80's, it's still a viable platform that's powering more than you think it does.

Comment: I'm currently doing COBOL to migrate platform from AIX to Postgres, but still powered by cobol, furthermore GnuCobol is a project very active at the moment.